# Is it possible to natively lazy load images that have no dimensions specified (because they need to be responsive)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, lazy-loading

**I am aware** that in order for browser native lazy loadig to work properly (in chrome), you need to define image height and width.

**The problem is** that i need my images to be responsive, so i am not able to set absolute height and width. Yet i still want to lazy load these images to increase my website's performance.

**I tried** hacking my way around this by wrapping the images in a div that has an aspect ratio, then setting the image height and width to 100%. Unforunately it seems that only absolute dimensions work.

Is there even a possible workaround to natively lazy load images without absolute dimensions, or should i use a javascript library to do this (or, are they not able to fix this as well)?

*side note: i noticed that this is only a problem in chrome. whats the point of this technique if you cant use it on responsive images like 99% of us need.*

Comment: perhaps there's something you're doing wrong in your "code"

Comment: @Bravo with "code" do you mean html? because all it takes to natively lazy load is adding loading="lazy" to your img tag, and for the dimensions part: that is my question. is there a workaround or should i use a third party library to lazy load images if i don't know the height or width.

Comment: you tagged "javascript" and "html" ... so, I assume both - have you considered using `<img srcset=.... sizes=....` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images